# Whats the most efficient/nicest way to extract a text value from a HTML tag using Symfony DOM Crawler?

Tags: html, regex, xml, symfony, domcrawler

Given the following HTML code snippet:

```
<div class="item">
  large
  <span class="some-class">size</span>
</div>
```

I'm looking for the best way to extract the string "large" using Symfony's Crawler.

```
$crawler = new Crawler($html);
```

Here I could use `$crawler->html()` then apply a regex search. Is there a better solution?
Or how would you do it exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just found a solution that looks the cleanest to me:

```
$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$result = $crawler->filterXPath('//text()')->text();
```

Comment: `$result = $crawler->filterXPath('//div[@class="item"]/text()')->text();` would be better.

Comment: I think we actually don't need this extra selector as the div.item node has already been selected because thats the root node

Comment: But you will never have to handle this sole html snippet, I suppose it may be used when retrieve a large a full html source.

Comment: I'm using css selectors, I'm forced to use xpath just at the end somehow like this: $crawler->filter('div.item')->filterXPath('//text()')->text();

Answer (score 0):

```
$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$node = $crawler->filterXPath('//div[@class="item"]');
$domElement = $node->getNode(0);
foreach ($node->children() as $child) {
    $domElement->removeChild($child);
}
dump($node->text()); die();
```

After you have to trim whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky as the text that you're trying to get is a text node that the `DOMCrawler` component doesn't (as far as I know) allow you to extract. Thankfully DOMCrawler is just a layer over the top of PHP's DOM classes which means you could probably do something like:

```
$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$crawler = $crawler->filterXPath('//div[@class="item"]');
$domNode = $crawler->getNode(0);
$text = null;

foreach ($domNode->children as $domChild) {
    if ($domChild instanceof \DOMText) {
        $text = $domChild->wholeText;
        break;
    }
}
```

This wouldn't help with HTML like:

```
<div>
    text
    <span>hello</span>
    other text
</div>
```

So you would only get "text", not "text other text" in this instance. Take a look at the [`DOMText`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domtext.php#domtext.props.wholetext) documentation for more details.